# Need a little SQL help - Getting number of items in common

Tags: sql, sql-server

Imagine I have a table like such

```
UserID      Name      Hobbies
00001       Jim       Baseball, Hockey, Astonomy
00002       Jack      Baseball, Football, Video Games
00003       Jill      Astronomy, Shopping, Soccer
00004       Jane      Hockey, Astronomy, Video Games
00005       Jacob     Football, Basketball, Video Games
```

Now, what I want to do is get a count of hobbies in common.  So, let's say I plug in 00001 into a textbox or query string or whatever.  I want to see something like:

```
Name    Hobbies
Jack    You have (1) hobby in common
Jill    You have (1) hobby in common
Jane    You have (2) hobbies in common
Jacob   You have (0) hobbies in common
```

How would I write the code for that?  I'm stumped.  I'm thinking it's got to do with string matching, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Do not store data like comma separated items. It will only cause you lots of problems! One hobby / row.

Comment: As @jarlh elluded, if you have properly normalized data this is super painless. But when you have denormalized data you have to first parse it, then do your comparison. When you have well defined ddl the dml is easy.

Comment: If you really really want to keep it the structure like that, just use string splitting function to split the row into several rows, and then you can just use group by

Answer (score 1):

The first choice is to fix your data structure.  Comma-delimited lists are bad, bad, bad.  A separate table storing one row per person and per hobby is good, good, good.

If you are stuck with someone else's bad decisions, there is a little recourse.  First Google "sql server split" and get your favorite string splitting function.

Then, you can do:

```
with t as (
      select t.*, s.val as hobby
      from table t cross apply
           dbo.split(t.Hobbies, ', ') as s(val) -- Note, some `split()` implementations also have a `pos` value
     )
select t.userName, count(tuser.userId) as NumInCommon
from t left join
     t tuser
     on t.hobby = tuser.hobby and tuser.userId = '00001'
group by t.userId, t.userName;
```

It is not worth constructing the full sentence in SQL, unless you really want to.  Use SQL primarily to get the data you want.  (Formatting in SQL can be useful sometimes, but it is really more for the application code.)

Answer (score 0):

```
create table #temp_hobbies
(hobby_id int
,hobby varchar(50))

insert into #temp_hobbies values
(1, 'football')
,(2,'baseball')


create table #temp_people
(user_ids int,
name varchar(50),
hobby_ids int)
insert into #temp_people values
(01,'Adam',1)
,(01,'Adam',2)
,(02,'Dave',1)
,(03,'Matt',2)

select count(distinct hobby) , count(distinct name)
from #temp_hobbies a
inner join #temp_people b on a.hobby_id = b.hobby_ids
```

part of your solution you now need to add query that will give computed column of each user's hobby compared to other.
But per other user's try seperating hobby's into a seperate table and use int to do joins. Sql server is faster to process ints than varchar's esp if you will need to do this for thousand's of records.

Comment: this query solves what your looking for... thanks... 
select b.user_ids,b.name,common_hobbies =count(c.user_ids)/2
--from #temp_hobbies a
from #temp_people b
left join  #temp_people c on b.hobby_ids = c.hobby_ids
group by b.user_ids,b.name

Answer (score 0):

First of all please NORMALIZE your data. you can see lot of repeatating hobbies in each row, also it will be tedious to serach and for maintainability.

you can have all your USERS data in one table as below :

```
CREATE TABLE USERS ( UserID , NAME ); --> USERID being PRIMARY KEY
```

you can have all your HOBBIES in another table as below :

```
CREATE TABLE HOBBIES ( HOBBYID, HOBBYNAME); --> HOBBYID being PRIMARY KEY
```

you can have another table which maps USERS with HOBBIES as below :

```
CREATE USERS_HOBBIES( USERID , HOBBYID );
```

once the table is normalized as above, you can get the desired result by querying as below :

```
SELECT u.NAME , count(*) AS Hobbies FROM USERS u INNER JOIN
USERS_HOBBIES uh ON u.UserID  = uh.USERID INNER JOIN HOBBIES h ON
uh.HOBBYID = h.HOBBYID WHERE h.HOBBYID IN (
  (SELECT a.HOBBYID as HOBBYID FROM 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(HOBBYID) as HOBBYID FROM USERS_HOBBIES WHERE 
     USERID   = '00001' ) a INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(HOBBYID) as HOBBYID FROM USERS_HOBBIES WHERE 
     USERID <> '00001' ) b ON a.HOBBYID = b.HOBBYID) ) 
 AND u.USERID = '00001'  GROUP BY u.NAME
```

P.S : The above query syntax is in ORACLE